# Remove path from variable name in a dataframe

Tags: r

I've put together a function that looks like this, with the first comment lines being an example. Most importantly here is the `set.path` variable that I use to set the path initially for the function.

```
# igor.import(set.path = "~/Desktop/Experiment1 Folder/SCNavigator/Traces",
#                          set.pattern = "StepsCrop.ibw",
#                          remove.na = TRUE)


igor.multifile.import <- function(set.path, set.pattern, remove.na){
    {
        require("IgorR")
        require("reshape2")

        raw_list  <- list.files(path= set.path,
                                pattern= set.pattern,
                                recursive= TRUE,
                                full.names=TRUE)
        multi.read <- function(f) {                                      # Note that "temp.data" is just a placeholder in the function
            temp_data <- as.vector(read.ibw(f))                          # Change extension to match your data type
        }
        my_list           <- sapply(X = raw_list, FUN = multi.read)      # Takes all files gathered in raw_list and applies multi.read()
        my_list_combined  <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, my_list))

        my_list_rotated <- t(my_list_combined[nrow(my_list_combined):1,]) # Matrix form
        data_out <- melt(my_list_rotated)                                 # "Long form", readable by ggplot2
        data_out$frame <- gsub("V", "", data_out$Var1)
        data_out$name  <- gsub(set.path, "", data_out$Var2) # FIX THIS
    }
    if (remove.na == TRUE){
    set_name <- na.omit(data_out)
    } else if (remove.na == FALSE) {
        set_name <- data_out
    } else (set_name <- data_out)
}
```

When I run this function I'll get a large dataframe, where each file that matched the pattern will show up with a name like

```
/Users/Joh/Desktop/Experiment1 Folder/SCNavigator/Traces/Par994/StepsCrop.ibw`
```

that includes the entire filepath, and is a bit unwieldy to look at and deal with.

I've tried to remove the path part with the line that says

```
data_out$name  <- gsub(set.path, "", data_out$Var2)
```

Similar to the command above that removes the dataframe auto-named V1, V2, V3... (which works). I can't remove the string part matching the `set.path = "my/path/"` though.

Comment: First, please clarify your question: what exactly do you want, i.e "this is input -- this is desired output" -- not very clear from your post what you are trying to achieve. Second, have you tried to use  `basename(path)` and `dirname(path)` https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/basename.html

Comment: Sorry about that.It turns out that if you input e.g. `~/Desktop/`, R will write it as `/Users/Username/Desktop/` in your file, causing a mismatch in the gsub command that is looking for `~/` that was initially inputted.

Comment: How about `gsub(paste0(".*", sub('~', '', set.path)), "", data_out$Var2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what your `set.path` is, you can eliminate it by

`gsub(".*/","",mypath)`

`mypath<-"/Users/Joh/Desktop/Experiment1 Folder/SCNavigator/Traces/Par994/StepsCrop.ibw"
gsub(".*/","",mypath)
[1] "StepsCrop.ibw`"

`

Comment: I ended up going with `data_out$name  <- gsub(paste(c(set.path, set.pattern, "/"), collapse = "|"), "", data_out$Var2)`. Seems less cryptic.